# What is the best way to include all images from folder in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pdf

I have downloaded a pdf viewer for my website (see: http://codecanyon.net/item/real-3d-flipbook-jquery-plugin/4281720), and I have a question about it.

I want to add around 60 - 70 pages to this flip book but I don't know how I can do this. I tried several solutions I found on the internet but I can't get it to work. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>PDF flipbook</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./source/css/flipbook.style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./source/css/font-awesome.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./source/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./source/js/flipbook.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
      var options = {
        pages:[
          { src: "./source/pages/1.jpg", thumb: "./source/pages/1thumb.jpg", title:"Page 1"},
          { src: "./source/pages/2.jpg", thumb: "./source/pages/2thumb.jpg", title:"Page 2"},
          { src: "./source/pages/3.jpg", thumb: "./source/pages/3thumb.jpg", title:"Page 3"},
          { src: "./source/pages/4.jpg", thumb: "./source/pages/4thumb.jpg", title:"Page 4"}
        ],
        singlePageModeIfMobile: true,
        btnDownloadPdf : {
          enabled:false
        },
        btnToc : {
          enabled:false
        },
        btnDownloadPages : {
          enabled:false
        },
        btnPrint : {
          enabled:false
        },
        viewMode:'3d'
      };

      $("#book").flipBook(options);
    })
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="book"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I quickly add al 65 images from the /source/pages map to 'pages'?
I hope I explained it all well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all the page images and titles are in sequential numeric order you could use a simple loop to generate them:

```
var pageArray = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 65; i++) {
   pageArray.push({ 
       src: './source/pages/' + i + '.jpg', 
       thumb: './source/pages/' + i + 'thumb.jpg', 
       title: 'Page ' + i 
    })
}

var options = {
    pages: pageArray,
    // other settings...
}
```